# Disable line break in boxes

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem in CSS. I have a box and when I put in the content a 'long' HTML code, it makes a line break.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

My CSS code:

```
.well {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 100%;
  margin-right: -90%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  text-align:center;
}
```

My PHP code:

```
echo '<a href="http://test.net/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=',$fid,'">',$q->username,'</a>','<form class="navbar-form" action="delete.php" method="GET"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Delete</button></form><br/><br/>';
```

I want to disable this line breaking.

Comment: That looks a lot like a bootstrap css. Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: No im using only the style

Comment: Could you please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that recreates this behavior?

Comment: Sure, http://jsfiddle.net/2efgv957/

Answer (score 0):

one way is to remove all breakline. Here's the code:
Consider all your content is inside a div with id="myContent", then

```
$('#myContent').find('br').remove();
```

And, if you want a more appropriate solution, please provide it in jsfiddle.